# Query not returning the expected results

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT u.* ,
(select CASE u.ID 
WHEN u.ID in (select RequestedUserID from user_requestes where userID=3)  THEN 0
ELSE 1
END ) AS Accepted
FROM users u 
WHERE u.ID <>3 
and u.id not in (select friends.FriendID 
             from friends 
             where friends.UserID=3 or friends.FriendID=3) 
order by u.Name asc
```

i am trying to execute this query using phpmyadmin

```
select RequestedUserID from user_requestes where userID=3
```

the above query return `79` as result

and if i execute the original query i found this

[image]

Accepted should be 0 and not 1

Comment: You never restrict the original query to have `Accepted` values of zero, so why should you expect this?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what if you write your query like this?

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    CASE
        WHEN u.ID IN (select RequestedUserID from user_requestes where userID=3) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS Accepted
FROM
    users u 
WHERE
    u.ID <>3 
    and u.id not in (
        select
            friends.FriendID 
        from
            friends 
        where
            friends.UserID=3 or friends.FriendID=3
    ) 
order by
    u.Name asc
```

- Don't use SELECT before CASE;
- If you go for CASE  WHEN... syntax, you must provide values and not search conditions ([See MySQL documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html))

Comment: @Thorsten is right. I came two minutes too late :-).

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your case expression

```
CASE u.ID WHEN u.ID in (...)
```

reads as follows: look up u.id in the subquery. Found = true, not found = false. In MySQL true = 1 and false = 0.

```
CASE u.ID WHEN <either 1 or 0>
```

You are mistakenly comparing the user ID with the boolean result 1 or 0.

You want this instead:

```
SELECT 
  u.* ,
  CASE 
    WHEN u.ID in (select RequestedUserID from user_requestes where userID=3) THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS Accepted
FROM ...
```

By the way: There is probably a semantical mistake in your friends subquery, as it is always FriendID you are returning. I suppose that should be:

```
and u.id not in 
(
  select case when FriendID = 3 then UserID else FriendID end
  from friends
  where UserID = 3 or FriendID = 3
)
```

or simply

```
and u.id not in (select FriendID from friends where UserID = 3)
and u.id not in (select UserID from friends where FriendID = 3)
```

Comment: my aim is to see if this friend exist in user_requestes i want to set acceptable as 0 else i need acceptable to be 1

Comment: Yes, I understand this. This is what `case when u.id in (...)` does. `case u.id when u.id in (...)`, however, does something else that you didn't intend.

Comment: Er, ... "this friend"? Yor where clause gets *non-friends*.

Answer (score 0):

This might work better:

```
SELECT  u.*,
        IF(EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                    from  user_requestes
                    where  userID = 3
                      AND  RequestedUserID = u.ID ),
           0, 1 ) AS Accepted
    FROM  users AS u
    LEFT JOIN  friends AS f  ON f.FriendID = u.ID
    WHERE  u.ID != 3
      AND  f.FriendID IS NULL
      AND  ( f.UserID = 3  or  f.FriendID = 3 )
```

Note the use of `EXISTS` as being more efficient than `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  Ditto for `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`.